# Bootstrap datepicker two way function

Tags: javascript, jscript, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I have a bootstrap datepicker I wanted to create a date range in one object only and triggered by pressing shift key and when the user clicked ctrl key the function will shift to multi dates is that possible? Sorry I am just a newbie in Javascript. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you so much!

Here is what I have so far.

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="multi"  name="multi" required>
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#multi').datepicker({
        multidate: true,
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        forceParse: false

    }).on('hide', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
</script>

$("#multi").on('keydown', function (event) {
if (event.shiftKey === true) {
    isShift = true;
      //alert(isShift);
      console.log(isShift);
  //  isCtrl = false;
} else if (event.ctrlKey === true) {
    //alert('ey ctrl press');
    isCtrl = true;
    console.log(isCtrl);
    //isShift = false;
} else {
   
    return false
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me understand.. Do you want detect shift and ctrl press, together?

When you press "shift" key, the condition that checks "ctrl" has not been called, because you are using else if.

Try:

```
$("#multi").on('keydown', function (event) {

if (event.shiftKey === true) {
   isShift = true;
} else {
   isShift = false;
}

if (event.ctrlKey === true) {
    isCtrl = true;
} else {
    isCtrl = false;
}

if(isCtrl && isShift) {

// do something

} else {
    return false;
}

});
```

Comment: Yes when shift key is click I want to get the date range. Example I clicked Jan 1 and Jan 3 all in between dates will be highlighted/selected. Then when ctrl key is selected i want to get/select the multidates user clicked. Can you guide me do that? Sorry I am just a newbie.